# Suspend doesn't work after Ubuntu 15.10 update

Tags: suspend, 15.10, hp

I have an HP Spectre x360 laptop, and I dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 Pro. I've resorted to downgrading to Ubuntu 15.04 because the suspend feature critical for well...any laptop simply doesn't work at all on my machine running Ubuntu 15.10. I've tried all sorts of things, and I've upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10 as well as tried fresh installing 15.10. If I close the laptop or select suspend after pressing the power button, the display turns black and the computer becomes entirely unresponsive. The power light never pulses, indicating that the machine has not actually been suspended. The only way to get out of this state is to force shut down the computer by holding the power button. This problem is entirely absent on Ubuntu 15.04, so I'm curious what exactly 'broke' when 15.10 was released.

Answer (score 1):

You could try editing /etc/default/grub by modifying the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT field such that `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`. 
After that, just run `sudo update-grub`.

I had a problem with the suspend as well as with the brightness controller and luckily I solved both problems thanks to this article that explains exactly what I said above:

[[SOLVED] Brightness problem in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin](http://www.techjail.net/solved-brightness-problem-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin.html)

I also use Ubuntu 15.10. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.